# Как определять положение и высоту объекта jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли определить див относительно объекта $(window)

Например у меня есть родительский элемент $(window) или `<body height='100%'>` в нем лижет какой-то еще элемент у которого например высота 300px, за этим элементом следует другой элемент но высота у него может быть любая, так вот собственно вопрос: можно ли как то определять положение этого элемента относительно объекта $(window) с учетом верхнего объекта и если он не помещается в область видимость $(window) или `<body>` задать ему такую высоту что бы оно поместился учитываю что выше может быть элемент с любой высотой, как это сделать я не понимаю.

```
<body> /* например body 500px(значение может быть любое оно должно реагировать на .on('load resize', function()) он же может быть и $(window) безразницы */
  <div class='object-1'></div> /* Этот объект напрмер 300px занчение может быть любое */
  <div class='adaptive height'></div> /* Этот объект должен принять такую высоту что бы не вылазить за пределы body или $(window) */
</body>
```

Comment: Так посчитайте разницу между высотой станицы и первого дива

Comment: @yolosora да спс, так и сделал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял условие задачи, то посмотрите мое решение:

```js
var box = document.querySelector(".box");
var two = document.querySelector(".box__two");
var one = document.querySelector(".box__one");

two.style.height = (box.offsetHeight - one.offsetHeight) / 2 + "px";
two.style.width = (box.offsetWidth - one.offsetWidth) / 2 + "px";
```

```css
.box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.box__one {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #f00;
  margin: 5px auto;
}

.box__two {
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box__one"></div>
  <div class="box__two"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: А спасибо подтолкнули на мысль

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
    var windowHeight = $(window).height(),
        containerTop = $('.module__info__content').offset(),
        containerHeight = $('.module__info__content');

    var newHeight = windowHeight - containerTop.top;

    containerHeight.height(newHeight - 120)
});
```